# Yum is not working anymore in scientific linux after python update

Tags: python, linux, redhat, yum

Im using a scientific linux on a remote machine. I tried to install python 2.7 on it. After that the yum and some other python packages are not working (it says "no module named yum"). I searched it online and it seems I should not have touched the system python as it breaks some of the system tools. Is there a way to reinstall the previous python (which was 2.6). I already tried to install python 2.6 by downloading the package but still yum is not working.

Comment: Oof. Try [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/611048/89174) at Server Fault?

Comment: That solution is for centos not scientific linux. Anyways, I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: CentOS and Scientific Linux are super close to each other. Download the RPMs from [here](http://mirrors.asnet.am/scientific/6x/x86_64/os/Packages/), perhaps.

Comment: I downloaded similar packages as those mentioned in the post. However after typing yum now I get the error: "There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named time"

Comment: I have a weird problem now. After typing python and entering it I can import yum and time with no error. but when typing yum in the terminal I get "no module named time".

Comment: Problem solved. It seems that I had two versions of python. The problem is solved after fixing the symlink. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your system back to normal, add Python 2.7 as a Software Collection - it installs "along side" the original Python 2.6 rather than replace it so both are available without collision.  Get 2.7 and others from softwarecollections.org.